# Implementing gradient operator in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I'm working on a Computer Vision system and this is giving me a serious headache. I'm having trouble re-implementing an old gradient operator more efficiently, I'm working with numpy and openCV2.

This is what I had:

```
def gradientX(img):
    rows, cols = img.shape
    out = np.zeros((rows,cols))
    for y in range(rows-1):
        Mr = img[y]
        Or = out[y]
        Or[0] = Mr[1] - Mr[0]
        for x in xrange(1, cols - 2):
            Or[x] = (Mr[x+1] - Mr[x-1])/2.0
        Or[cols-1] = Mr[cols-1] - Mr[cols-2]
    return out

def gradient(img):
    return [gradientX(img), (gradientX(img.T).T)]
```

I've tried using numpy's gradient operator but the result is not the same
For this input

```
array([[  3,   4,   5],
   [255,   0,  12],
   [ 25,  15, 200]])
```

Using my `gradient` returns

```
[array([[   1.,    0.,    1.],
   [-255.,    0.,   12.],
   [   0.,    0.,    0.]]), 
array([[ 252.,   -4.,    0.],
   [   0.,    0.,    0.],
   [-230.,   15.,    0.]])]
```

While using numpy's `np.gradient` returns

```
[array([[ 252. ,   -4. ,    7. ],
   [  11. ,    5.5,   97.5],
   [-230. ,   15. ,  188. ]]), 
array([[   1. ,    1. ,    1. ],
   [-255. , -121.5,   12. ],
   [ -10. ,   87.5,  185. ]])]
```

There are cleary some similarities between the results but they're definitely not the same. So I'm missing something here or the two operators aren't mean to produce the same results. In that case, I wanted to know how to re-implement my gradientX function so it doesn't use that awful looking double loop for traversing the 2-d array using mostly numpy's potency.

Comment: @Peque OP is clearly trying to use numpy, but is saying that the default numpy gradient doesn't give the same result as his pure python function.  Therefore, he wants to know how to rewrite his gradient function using numpy.

Comment: Can you explain what gradientX computes?  Your gradient function returns the same thing as `numpy.gradient(img)[::-1]` with certain rows/columns set to zero.

Comment: It's a finite difference aproximation to a 1st derivative in the X axis. Same as what you can achieve with the gradient operator in Matlab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been working a bit more on this just to find that my mistake.
I was skipping last row and last column when iterating. As @wflynny noted, the result was identical except for a row and a column of zeros.

Provided this, the result could not be the same as np.gradient, but with that change, the results are identical, so there's no need to find any other numpy implementation for this.

Answering my own question, a good numpy's implementation for my gradient algorithm would be

```
import numpy as np
def gradientX(img):
    return np.gradient(img)[::-1]
```

I'm also posting the working code, just because it shows how numpy's gradient operator works

```
def computeMatXGradient(img):
    rows, cols = img.shape
    out = np.zeros((rows,cols))
    for y in range(rows):
        Mr = img[y]
        Or = out[y]
        Or[0] = float(Mr[1]) - float(Mr[0])
        for x in xrange(1, cols - 1):
            Or[x] = (float(Mr[x+1]) - float(Mr[x-1]))/2.0
        Or[cols-1] = float(Mr[cols-1]) - float(Mr[cols-2])
    return out
```

Comment: did you have the same result from `gradientX` and `computeMatXGradient`?